# Running Visual Assist X and ReSharper 5.0 at the same time

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-assist

VS 2005/2008/2010

I have latest Visual Assist X and Resharper 5.0 installed at the same time. I found some Resharper shortkeys and functionality became disabled or stopped working. Do these 2 plugins conflict? How do I check what has been disabled by Visual Assist X in ReSharper? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Also, Visual Assist X overlaps some of Visual Studio's functionality: Navigation bar, quick info, parameter info...

So I have to go to option and hide VS's navigation bar. I also wonder if I need to turn off VS's intellisense, since Visual Assist parses all the files anyway, so the intellisense might be wasting CPU time despite not being in use.

Comment: @schoetbi, presumably. Fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Assist does not knowingly disable any Resharper feature.  Current builds of Visual Assist will disable some of its own features when it detects the presence of Resharper.  [Contact Whole Tomato support](http://www.wholetomato.com/support/contact.asp) for any issues you may be experiencing.